# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat not starting when using spring boot 2.6.2 and above

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I start a new spring boot application based on the spring boot 2.6.2. The application is very simple, just helloworld with web-mvc and spring-security. I have done it several times before, but this time the tomcat doesn't start up when the application runs.  The pom.xml is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the console is as below when the application starts:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=12156:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\code\example\java\spring-demo\target\classes;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-security-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.3\spring-boot-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.10\logback-classic-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.10\logback-core-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.1\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.33\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.15\spring-aop-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.15\spring-beans-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.6.1\spring-security-config-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.15\spring-context-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.6.1\spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.15\spring-expression-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.1\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.1\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.1\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.15\spring-web-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.15\spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.33\slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.15\spring-core-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.15\spring-jcl-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.6.1\spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.6.1\spring-security-crypto-5.6.1.jar" com.demo.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-01-22 23:39:59.885  INFO 47256 --- [           main] c.c.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication     : Starting SpringDemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_301 on 5YUOP71L7Z3I7K5 with PID 47256 (E:\code\example\java\spring-demo\target\classes started by Administrator in E:\code\example\java\spring-demo)
2022-01-22 23:39:59.887  INFO 47256 --- [           main] c.c.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-22 23:40:00.295  INFO 47256 --- [           main] c.c.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication     : Started SpringDemoApplication in 0.642 seconds (JVM running for 1.088)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am sure the problem has something to do with spring boot version 2.6.2. Because when I change the version to 2.6.1 and below, everything is ok as usual. And version 2.6.3 doesn't work either. That's really an unexpected trap. Is there anyone who knows anything about it?

ps:The code is as below:

```
package com.demo.springdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: The output is of IDEA IntelliJ console. Please try to start on plain command line via `java -jar ...` instead ...

Comment: Can you share your main class?

Comment: I suspect that you have a corrupted Tomcat jar on the classpath. Trying running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` so that Maven will delete your application's dependencies from its local cache. It will then download them again when you next build your application.

Comment: @Wilkinson You are right. Thanks a lot. Really a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. The result was in my expectation because the spring-boot-starter-tomcat has been imported by spring-boot-starter-web already.